# Is there a way to delete time values in an xarray dataset that does not meet a certain time value?

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime, python-xarray, era5

[image: Description of the data set]
This ERA5 dataset, made up of netCDF files, comes in time values of %Y-%m-%dT%h:%M%s %p and they are given hourly. So, for 31 days, there are 744-time values. I only want to take the 12:00:00 value for each day so that I have 31 data points. Eventually I want to do this for data sets longer than a month as well.

I tried a few different things from various other posts on this site. A few of them include:

```
df = df[df['time'].dt.hour == 12]
```

I also tried the ison function.

I ended up getting the following error: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'DataArray'`

I am sure it has something to do with the way I am inputting datetime. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Matthew! Welcome to StackOverflow! The code you have works for dataframes, but it seems like your data isn't a dataframe.

Comment: Why didn't you simply download the 12:00 value in the first place? ~30 times less data to handle and store.   with cdo though you could just do cdo selhour,12 i think.

Comment: for xarray data sets / data arrays, see also [Indexing and selecting data](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/user-guide/indexing.html)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for Xarray's [`where`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.where.html) method:

```
df2 = df.where(df.time.dt.hour == 12, drop=True)
```